# Deleting a Mac user account after logout

Tags: mac, active-directory, users

I am developing an image for a maclab, and I am running into an issue with Snow Leopard. We have set up the machines on active directory so network users can login, however after they logoff their user folders are still in there and I am not really sure how to go about auto deleting there information from the Mac machine.

Answer (score 2):

User folders for portable homes will remain on a machine as a local cache of a user's complete profile. Deleting these folders would create significant strain on the network as the machine would have to pull and sync the user's profile every single time at log in, instead of lazy sync at log in and log out.  Permissions are retained, so you don't have to worry about information being accessible to other users. This [PDF](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/User_Management_v10.6.pdf) contains a section on external accounts and portable directories and how Snow Leopard works with Open Directory and Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

What Madison says is true, I wanted to ask if you are "Forcing Local Home folders" on the Macs when you bind them to the AD. You can uncheck that option and make the homes stay on the server. This may not be practical if you don't have enough resources on the server to handle home folders.

If you're creating Mobile accounts, there's probably a way to expire them in AD. In OS X Server, the option is in the Workgroup Manager, under the Preferences area and under the Mobility pane. In the "Account Expiry" tab, you can set the accounts, and the home folders, to disappear hours or days after the last login. This is great for lab situations.

If the feature exists in OS X Server, there's probably something similar in AD.